# FTS search terms as a separate column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, highlighting

I have a long list of search keywords in a Postgres FTS query. The query goes through hundreds of documents and picks the documents that include search keywords. In the result, I woud need a column that shows which search keyword matched with the document, so that it can be used to group the documents further. The highlighted match directly from the text in ts_headline does not allow this because the highlighted terms are in many different forms and the result is irregular.

With this type of query

```
to_tsquery(‘english’, ‘Donald | Mickey | Goofy’)
```

I would like a result like this:

```
text:                             keyword:
Donald Duck’s house lorem ipsum   Donald
Mickey Mouse lorem impsum         Mickey 
Lorem ipsum goofiness             Goofy
```

Comment: `'StartSel="",StopSel="",ShortWord=1000,MinWords=1,MaxWords=2,MaxFragments=1'` for `ts_headline` [almost does the trick](http://rextester.com/APDDY16089). It will only fail when there are two adjacent matching words. There is an annoying limitation that `MinWords` must be greater than `0` and `MaxWords` must be greater than `MinWords`. -- I don't think it's possible without `ts_headline` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
select doc, string_agg(term, ', ')
from
    (values
        ('Donald Duck''s house lorem ipsum'),
        ('Mickey Mouse lorem impsum'),
        ('Lorem ipsum goofiness'),
        ('Donald, Mickey, lorem impsum and Goofy')
    ) v(doc)
    cross join
    (values ('Donald'),('Mickey'),('Goofy')) s (term)
where to_tsvector(doc) @@ to_tsquery(term)
group by doc
;
                  doc                   |      string_agg       
----------------------------------------+-----------------------
 Donald Duck's house lorem ipsum        | Donald
 Donald, Mickey, lorem impsum and Goofy | Donald, Mickey, Goofy
 Lorem ipsum goofiness                  | Goofy
 Mickey Mouse lorem impsum              | Mickey
```